# Replace not working on XML nodes

Tags: xml, powershell, replace

I have a bunch of XML files that I need to do a few replace operations on within the node text. My code can't seem to update the `<Notes>` node as it can't be found. I've checked the XML path in Notepad++ and it looks correct.

This is a sample XML file I am using to test with.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="21">
    <OrganisationId>ORG1</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>ORG 1 TEST</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressId>E41002</AddressId>
        <MainAddress>Y</MainAddress>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
    <ContactDetails>
      <ContactDetailsRow num="1">
        <ContactId>E6366</ContactId>
        <ContactCode>OFFICE</ContactCode>
        <Main>N</Main>
        <Notes>start date 11/03/1994</Notes>
      </ContactDetailsRow>
      <ContactDetailsRow num="2">
        <ContactId>E6367</ContactId>
        <ContactCode>WORK</ContactCode>
        <Main>N</Main>
        <Notes>start date 11/03/1995</Notes>
      </ContactDetailsRow>
      <ContactDetailsRow num="3">
        <ContactId>E6368</ContactId>
        <ContactCode>HOME</ContactCode>
        <Main>Y</Main>
        <Notes>start date - after 11/03/1995</Notes>
      </ContactDetailsRow>
      <ContactDetailsRow num="4">
        <ContactId>E6369</ContactId>
        <ContactCode>EMAIL</ContactCode>
        <ContactCodeDesc>Email Address</ContactCodeDesc>
        <ContactValue>info@yahoo.com</ContactValue>
        <StartDate>2000-03-11</StartDate>
        <Main>N</Main>
        <Notes>more test notes</Notes>
      </ContactDetailsRow>
    </ContactDetails>
    <Sector>P</Sector>
    <SectorDesc>Private</SectorDesc>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

and this is my script.

```cs
#----- get source xml file(e) from the folder below ---#
$path = "C:\Dump\TEST"
$Files = Get-Childitem -path $path -File -include test_file_1.xml -name

# For every file in the folder specified perform a series of actions below
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    Write-Host "=== FILE is $File ===" -ForegroundColor "White"
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $path\$File)

    ## SectorDesc
    # check to ensure that we have got a SectorDesc row
    foreach ($OrganisationUnitsRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow)
    {
        if ($OrganisationUnitsRow.Item('SectorDesc'))
        {
            $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.SectorDesc = $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.SectorDesc.Replace("`b" , "\b")             #backspace
            $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.SectorDesc = $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.SectorDesc.Replace("`f" , "\f")             #form feed
        }
    }

    ## Notes
    # check to ensure that we have got a Notes row
    foreach ($ContactDetailsRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails.ContactDetailsRow)
    {
        if ($ContactDetailsRow.Item('Notes'))
        {
            Write-Host "$ContactDetailsRow.Notes"
            $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails.ContactDetailsRow.Notes = $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails.ContactDetailsRow.Notes.Replace("\" , "\\")                #back slash
            $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails.ContactDetailsRow.Notes = $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails.ContactDetailsRow.Notes.Replace("`b" , "\b")             #backspace
        }

    }

    $xml.Save("$path\$File")
}
```

When the script runs it throws an error.

```
Property 'Notes' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is
settable.
At C:\Dump\test10.ps1:33 char:8
+                 $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails.ContactDetails ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Property 'Notes' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is
settable.
At C:\Dump\test10.ps1:34 char:8
+                 $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails.ContactDetails ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

I may be rather obvious but I can't see it straight away.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `$xml.Organis...ailsRow.Notes` gives you the `<Notes>` child node of *all* `<ContactDetailsRow>` nodes (in your example 4). Use your loop variable instead (and you can daisy-chain the `Replace()` calls):

```cs
foreach ($ContactDetailsRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.ContactDetails.ContactDetailsRow)
{
    if ($ContactDetailsRow.Item('Notes'))
    {           
        Write-Host "$ContactDetailsRow.Notes"
        $ContactDetailsRow.Notes = $ContactDetailsRow.Notes.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("`b", "\b")
    }
}
```

Better yet, directly select the `<Notes>` child nodes with an XPath expression:

```cs
$xml.SelectNodes('//ContactDetailsRow/Notes') | ForEach-Object {
    $_.'#text' = $_.'#text'.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("`b", "\b")
}
```

The reason why your code doesn't throw the same error for your first nested loop (where you made the same mistake) is that your XML sample contains only a single `<SectorDesc>` node, so it doesn't trigger the issue there.

Comment: Thanks to @Ansgar Wiechers to explanation as to why my code was wrong - good to have the reason why it was wrong